# How do I get Python in Visual Studio Code to retrieve API data every minute until a second button has been hit?

Tags: python, api, connection

I'm a Python novice, and use Visual Studio Code to code. At the moment, I need to connect to an API and retrieve data every minute until a second "Stop" button gets hit. I reiterate, I am a novice, and tried looking on here for some answers, but the results went over my head. Is there any way to solve the following in a way that is presentable to an audience? This is for a prototype, but this prototype will not be used for financial purposes, I give my word as a stranger on the internet.

This is what I have:

```py
import requests
import sys
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QTextBrowser, QPushButton
from PyQt6.QtGui import *
from PyQt6.QtCore import *

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Data Table")
        self.setGeometry(50, 50, 1200, 780)

        self.cldpct = QTextBrowser(self)
        self.cldpct.setGeometry(30, 60, 1145, 60)
        self.cldpct.setReadOnly(True)
        self.cldpct.setText("Cloud Coverage Percent")

        self.tmp = QTextBrowser(self)
        self.tmp.setGeometry(30, 130, 1145, 60)
        self.tmp.setReadOnly(True)
        self.tmp.setText("Current Temperature")

        self.flslk = QTextBrowser(self)
        self.flslk.setGeometry(30, 200, 1145, 60)
        self.flslk.setReadOnly(True)
        self.flslk.setText("Feels Like")

        self.hmd = QTextBrowser(self)
        self.hmd.setGeometry(30, 270, 1145, 60)
        self.hmd.setReadOnly(True)
        self.hmd.setText("Humidity")

        self.mntmp = QTextBrowser(self)
        self.mntmp.setGeometry(30, 340, 1145, 60)
        self.mntmp.setReadOnly(True)
        self.mntmp.setText("Minimum Temperature")

        self.mxtmp = QTextBrowser(self)
        self.mxtmp.setGeometry(30, 410, 1145, 60)
        self.mxtmp.setReadOnly(True)
        self.mxtmp.setText("Maximum Temperature")

        self.wndspd = QTextBrowser(self)
        self.wndspd.setGeometry(30, 480, 1145, 60)
        self.wndspd.setReadOnly(True)
        self.wndspd.setText("Wind Speed")

        self.wnddgr = QTextBrowser(self)
        self.wnddgr.setGeometry(30, 550, 1145, 60)
        self.wnddgr.setReadOnly(True)
        self.wnddgr.setText("Wind Degrees")

        self.snrtm = QTextBrowser(self)
        self.snrtm.setGeometry(30, 620, 1145, 60)
        self.snrtm.setReadOnly(True)
        self.snrtm.setText("Sunrise Time")

        self.snstm = QTextBrowser(self)
        self.snstm.setGeometry(30, 690, 1145, 60)
        self.snstm.setReadOnly(True)
        self.snstm.setText("Sunset Time")

        self.RtvBtn = QPushButton(self)
        self.RtvBtn.setGeometry(500, 25, 100, 25)
        self.RtvBtn.setText("Retrieve Results")  
        self.RtvBtn.clicked.connect(self.run_query)

        self.EndBtn = QPushButton(self)
        self.EndBtn.setGeometry(600, 25, 100, 25)
        self.EndBtn.setText("End Retrieval")
        self.EndBtn.clicked.connect(self.run_query)

    def run_query(self):

        city = 'Cheesetown'

        api_url = f'https://api.api-ninjas.com/v1/weather?city={city}'

        response = requests.get(api_url, headers={'X-Api-Key': 'API_Key'})
        if response.status_code == requests.codes.ok:
            print(response.text)
        else:
            self.cldpct.setText("Error:", response.status_code, response.text)
            self.tmp.setText("Error:", response.status_code, response.text)
            self.flslk.setText("Error:", response.status_code, response.text)
            self.hmd.setText("Error:", response.status_code, response.text)
            self.mntmp.setText("Error:", response.status_code, response.text)
            self.mxtmp.setText("Error:", response.status_code, response.text)
            self.wndspd.setText("Error:", response.status_code, response.text)
            self.wnddgr.setText("Error:", response.status_code, response.text)
            self.snrtm.setText("Error:", response.status_code, response.text)
            self.snstm.setText("Error:", response.status_code, response.text)

`if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

What I need this to do is connect to the API, using the API token (the current one is fake) and the response to be split into its consecutive results, and output into their own different "Results" tables, updating every minute. I tried converting the resulting text from the API service to a string, but that didn't quite work. If, in the process there is a way to simplify the code in a way that can still be shown and explained, that would be welcome.

(Yes, I know that I need to fix `self.EndBtn.clicked.connect(self.run_query)`, and that the UI is awful, but I'll try to fix that separately.)

What I'm looking for in the response is an answer from someone in the community, as I would like to do this project without the assistance of ChatGPT. This may seem ridiculous, but I feel that using ChatGPT takes away from the merit of *my* work. This is not the same for others, but I hope there is understanding.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: You don't need to write \` before every line of code. Just put \`\`\` before and after your entire block of code.